# How to JOIN on different tables based on column value

Tags: mysql

ads table
[Screenshot http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/6295/adsvo.png](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/6295/adsvo.png)

phones table
[Screenshot http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3713/phones.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3713/phones.png)

cars table
[Screenshot http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1035/carsm.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1035/carsm.png)

i have 3 tables ads,cars and phones.

i want to join tables is based on category in ads table.

and i tried this query but no luck,any helps?

```
SELECT *
  FROM `ads` 
  JOIN `ads.category` ON `ads.id` = `ads.category.id`
```

** i cant add comment any of your post,but i want it to be automatic based on category in ads table.

for example :-
if in table have phones category,i will automatic join phones table then

```
SELECT *
  FROM `ads` 
  JOIN `phone` ON `ads.id` = `phone.id`
```

if in table have cars category,i will automatic join cars table

```
SELECT *
  FROM `ads` 
  JOIN `cars` ON `ads.id` = `cars.id`
```

Comment: How are the tables related? what do you want your results to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the cars:

```
SELECT *
FROM ads JOIN cars ON ads.ID = cars.ID
```

to get the phone:

```
SELECT *
FROM ads JOIN phones ON ads.ID = phones.ID
```

to get both use a UNION:

```
SELECT ads.ID, ads.Title, ads.Desc, ads.category, 'Car' AS AdType, cars.Year AS Col1, cars.cc AS Col2, cars.transmission AS Col3
FROM ads JOIN cars ON ads.ID = cars.ID
UNION ALL SELECT ads.ID, ads.Title, ads.Desc, ads.category, 'Phone' AS AdType, phone.Model AS Col1, phone.Color AS Col2, '' AS Col3
FROM ads JOIN phones ON ads.ID = phones.ID
```

note: i would advise you to setup foreign keys in your cars and phones tables, to reference the ads.ID instead of using the ID field (Primary key?) of the child tables

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      ads.*,
            cars.year, cars.cc, cars.transmission,
            phones.model, phones.color
FROM        ads
  LEFT JOIN cars
  ON        cars.id = ads.id
  LEFT JOIN phones
  ON        phones.id = ads.id
```

Though i agree with @Scrum, you can left join them, then (in your code) use the type field and retrieve the correct columns.

I also feel like these columns should be NULLABLE and all in one table. I don't see the point in breaking these off in their own with a 1-1 relation (and direct key relationship). This certainly isn't normalization (that I can see). *maybe I'm tired and inept*

Comment: i think its the other thing, not the tired and inept